# Setting up a triple integral to find the volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following exercise:

> Find the volume of the tetrahedron cut from the first octant by the plane $6x+3y+2z=6$

Now after sketching the tetrahedron I set up the following integral $\iiint1 dzdydx$
With the following bounds:
 $z=0$ to $z=3-3x-\frac{3}{2}y$
$y=0$ to $y=2-2x$
$x=0$ to $x=2-2y$

However in the solution which was set up in the same order x goes from $0$ to $1$, I understand they got these bound by observing the graph setting both $y$ and $z$ to $0$ but why do we do that?
After setting up the $z$ bounds if we set $z=0$ and draw the line $y=2-2x$ in the $x-y$ plane then when traveling along the x-axis the exit would be our line, and the $x$ value in that line isn't fixed to $x=1$ so why do we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the octahedron is in first octant, $x,y,z\geq 0$. Now we determine the boundary of integration.

$0\leq x\leq 1$

For a given $x$, $0\leq y\leq 2-2x$

For a given $x$ and $y$, $0\leq z\leq 3-3x-\frac{3}{2}y$

Comment: That wasn't my question. The answer you put is already in my post.

Comment: @AspiringMathematician notice how i work outside in i.e. determining boundary of $x$ first and $z$ last?

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. The order I picked could perfectly work and when you set up the integral you go from inside to outside.

Comment: @AspiringMathematician then could You please elaborate how You get the boundary of $x$ again? I am having a hard time trying to understand what You did

Answer (score 0):

Your limits for the $x$ variable are wrong. You can't make your $x$ variable limits depend on $x$ itself (you wrote $x = 2-2x$), since we have the $x$ variable ranging from a start value to an end value, if it depended on $x$ itself it would not make sense.

The limits for each variable must not depend on that variable. That's why we first establish one variable between two constants (for example, $0\le x\le 1$), the next one depending only on the previous one: $0 \le y \le 2x-2$, and finally the last one depending on the previous two ones: $0 \le z \le 3 - 3x - \frac{3}{2}y$. Of course, if you had more variables, this would carry on.

Finally, you set the integrals in that order:

$$\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{2x-2}\int_0^{3 - 3x - \frac{3}{2}y}dzdydx$$

Edit: Since you edited your post, and set $0 \le x \le 2y-2$, I'll say this still holds. You can't have $x$ depend on $y$ and $y$ depend on $x$ simultaneously, since your $x$ variable ranging between values of $y$ would change these $y$ values themselves.